# how to find non null or string.empty columns using linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

here's my code. it works

```
var someField = "abc";

var list = Entities.Where(x=>SomeField).FirstOrDefault();
```

here's the problem, someField can also be null or string.empty. If someField is null or string.empty, I will select everything where  SomeField is null or string.empty.

```
var list = Entities.Where(x=>SomeField  == null || SomeField == string.empty).FirstOrDefault();
```

right now, I have an if else statement to check if someField has value,then decided which query to use.

I need to combine the 2 queries into one. because if there are fields we need to check, then this if else statemetn will get very long.

Comment: In the first snippet you've implied that `SomeField` is of type `bool`. Now it's of type `string`? Your question is very unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you *actually* want to match `x.SomeField == someField`, or everything if `someField` is null or empty, right?

I would do this:

```
var fetchAll = string.IsNullOrEmpty(someField);
var list = Entities.FirstOrDefault(x => fetchAll || x.SomeField == someField);
```

You *can* inline it, but I think the above is clearer than checking whether `someField` is null or empty within the query.

Note that I've used the overload of `FirstOrDefault` which takes a predicate - this is equivalent to using `Where` followed by `FirstOrDefault`, but a bit more concise.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I suspect this is a more correct interpretation of the OP's intent.

Answer (score 1):

I did a little sample, I'm just getting the entity with a null or empty value in SomeField...

I hope this works for you.

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string SomeField { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
   List<MyEntity> Entities = new List<MyEntity>();
   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       Entities.Add(new MyEntity()
                   {
                       ID = i,
                       SomeField = "Value " + i.ToString()
                   });
   }

   Entities.Add(new MyEntity() { ID = 10, SomeField = null });
   var entity = Entities.Where(x => string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.SomeField)).FirstOrDefault();
}
```